# Открытие нового модального окна с закрытием предыдущего

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет пишу код на чистом html css jquery. Хочу чтоб при открытии второго модального окна закрывалось первое.

```
  const modalCall = $('[data-modal]');
  const modalClose = $('[data-close]');

  modalCall.on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let $this = $(this);
      let modalId = $this.data('modal');
      
      $(modalId).addClass('show');
      $('.slick-slider').slick('setPosition');
      $('body').addClass('no-scroll');

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(modalId).find('.modal__dialog').css({
          transform: 'rotateX(0)'
        });
      }, 200);
    });

    modalClose.on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    let $this = $(this);
    let modalParent = $this.parents('.modal');

    modalParent.find('.modal__dialog').css({
      transform: 'rotateX(90deg)'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      (modalParent).removeClass('show');
      $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    }, 200);
  });
  
  $('.modal').on("click", function(event) {
    let $this = $(this);

    $this.find('.modal__dialog').css({
      transform: 'rotateX(90deg)'
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.removeClass('show');
      $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    }, 200);

    worksSlider.slick('setPosition')
});

$('.modal__dialog').on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

я догадываюсь что я должен написать

```
$(modalId).hide();
```

Но не понимаю как правильно это сделать

Comment: $("#ид").hide() элемент и все лежащие в нем обьекты будут скрыты, после $("#ид1").show() будет показан второй объект

Comment: советую использовать arcticModal.js